# Get secret gists using Github GraphQL

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

As title, I'm using [Github GraphQL explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) to fetch list of my gists.

```
query {
  viewer {
    gists(first:5, privacy:ALL) {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    description
                    name
                    pushedAt
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Everything works fine except that the secret gists are not included in the response. When I tried to fetch secret gists by changing the `GistPrivacy` from `ALL` to `SECRET` as below:

```
query {
  viewer {
    gists(first:5, privacy:SECRET) {
            edges {
                node {
                    id
                    description
                    name
                    pushedAt
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

The following permission error occurred:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "gists": {
        "edges": []
      }
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "You don't have permission to see gists."
    }
  ]
}
```

I wonder is there any way to solve this problem. 
I noticed that there was a [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219804/gist-github-api-get-private-and-public-gists) with irrelevant answer asked 5 years ago.

Any comment or help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, although one can't get the secret gists from the [Github GraphQL explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/) directly, by creating a `Personal Access Tokens` and using it to access the GraphQL API, one can get the secret gists.

[image]

The equivalent curl command is as following:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.github.com/graphql \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"query":"query {\n  viewer {\n    gists(first:5, privacy:ALL) {\n\t\t\tedges {\n\t\t\t\tnode {\n\t\t\t\t\tid\n\t\t\t\t\tdescription\n\t\t\t\t\tname\n\t\t\t\t\tpushedAt\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n  }\n}"}'
```